# What is the closed form of the sequence $\left\lbrace 32, 422, 3406 , 22426,131995, ... \right\rbrace$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, closed-form

I am searching for a closed form of the following sequence:

$$\left\lbrace 32,422,3406,22426, 131995, ... \right\rbrace. \tag{1}$$

This shows up in the expansion of a complicated integral. The decomposition in prime numbers is:

$$32 = 2^5, \tag{2.1}$$
$$422 = 2 \cdot 211, \tag{2.2}$$
$$3406 = 2 \cdot 13 \cdot 131, \tag{2.3}$$
$$22426 = 2 \cdot 11213, \tag{2.4}$$
$$131995 = 5 \cdot 26399. \tag{2.5}$$

It is not obvious what to do with that. I am not a specialist of number theory, and I am not aware of techniques that could be used in order to find the closed form. I did search in [OEIS.org](http://oeis.org), without success.

Here is a plot of $(1)$:

[image]

Comment: so if you knew a sequence $a_n$ with the first terms as given, how do you know it's the sequence you're looking for? :o

Comment: @AlvinLepik Are you asking how I would be sure that the next numbers also match? I have the full integral (which involves a lot more terms, hence it is not given here) numerically, so I can check if the pattern matches. The coefficients above are obtained numerically as well, and from the data I guessed the closed form. So alternatively I could compute the next coefficients, although in practice this is hard and time-consuming.

Comment: OEIS has a "superseeker" function, which may be worth a try.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks for the tip, I didn't know that! Just sent a request, let's see if their algorithm can figure something out.

Comment: It will be helpful if you post the integral itself.

Comment: @piepie I cannot unfortunately: it is a sum of six very complicated and lengthy integrals involving logs and dilogs. I have reduced the integrals to a series in which I have found a closed form for everything except for the last bit that is in the question. Because of that, even knowing the original integral would not be helpful for finding the closed form of the sequence I believe.

Comment: It maybe tedious to type large equation in tex. You must have written the integral somewhere. You can upload photo, instead of typing in tex.

Comment: @piepie Not really, I have it in Mathematica but even there it is not straightforward to put it in a readable way. I'll look what I can do.

Comment: At first glance, your series grows slightly slower than exponentially. This makes it unlikely (though far from impossible; more terms would help, as 5 really isn't a lot) that it's, for instance, the solution of a linear recurrence relation with constant coefficients. It's conceivable that it could be hypergeometric, but again it's very hard to say. What reason do you have to believe that it has a nice characterization?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I do not have a good reason to believe that it has a nice characterization. I have done another integral where I was able to guess the closed form in that way, but it was a lot simpler than this one. This is the last bit of the integral that is not in closed form, so it is worth a try I think. Regarding your other comments, hypergeometric sounds plausible. I will try to get more terms.

Comment: Actually, the more I think about it the less I like hypergeometric — I would expect that to have mostly smaller prime factors. How many terms do you think you could compute explicitly?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki The next one is already going to be challenging. I have to think about how I could get more terms more efficiently. I will post an update tomorrow with more details in the question.

Answer (score 1):

A closed form of your sequence could be the following:

$a_n=49865-\frac{1273063}{12}n+\frac{615335}{8}n^2-\frac{278471}{12}n^3+\frac{61071}{24}n^4$

for any $n\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\}$.

Comment: Thanks, that's great! I will try it out tonight!